# Given a quad in 3D space with two diagonally opposite points and normal, how would I find the other two points?

Tags: vector, geometry, linear-algebra, normals

Image attached below for clarification:
[image]

So here we have a plane with a random rotation in 3D space, and we have the values for P1, P2, and the plane normal. How do I find the points X1 and X2?

This quad can have any width/height, any position, and any rotation.

Comment: I think we still have one degree of freedom too many here. With two diagonally opposite points in a plane, there are multiple possible rectangles that could be drawn through them, with different aspect ratios and "twist" about the plane normal. Do you have any additional constraint we can use to pick just one of these rectangles? It may help to explain what this is used for in your game — that application may suggest a metric that makes some rectangles a better choice than others.

Comment: @DMGregory Unfortunately these are all the constraints I have, other than world position and rotation. The two points are random and change at runtime.

Comment: Is it OK if we always return a square then? Or do you sometimes want rectangles of different aspect ratios for your application? I'll reiterate that telling us how this is used in your game would help us find suitable solutions.

Comment: To illustrate the point by @DMGregory, this rectangle would be possible as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckQnP.png. You would need to know either the aspect ratio of the rectangle or its rotation angle around the plane normal to find out the other two points.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks, I can see why that causes an issue.

Comment: @DMGregory Basically, there is an object with a render texture attached at runtime, and my system is supposed to slice a section from it,with the user dragging on a touchscreen in 3d space (essentially touch down and up locations) which are traced to the objects surface. The object is rotated at random in the application. I might be able to get the vertices of the parent

Comment: Ah, then you probably want the sides of the rectangle to align with the UV coordinate axes of the object's texture map? To get this, you'd want to have a tangent vector read from the hit point on the model. Or you could do the whole calculation in UV space where it's easier, then map to 3D.

Comment: @DMGregory Already doing that calculation in UV space so the resulting quad generated has the correct texture generated on it. The problem is aligning that quad in parallel to the hit position , so its just like a section floating on top. I think I might need to do that in tangent space like you mentioned.

Comment: If you know the positions and UV coordinates of the corners of the touchscreen quad, then you can map your UV space solution to a 3D solution using that data. Do you have those available?

Comment: @DMGregory I dont have access the touchscreen quad vertices which is why I'm stuck here :( I think I have access to a tangent vector which can give me an extra constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, to make this align with the texture displayed on your touch screen object, you'll also need a tangent vector. With that in hand (and assuming your tangent has unit length), we just do vector projection:

```
Vector3 diagonal = p2 - p1;
float width = Vector3.Dot(diagonal, tangent);
Vector3 side = tangent * width;

x2 = p1 + side;
x1 = p2 - side;
```